# An involution defined on the intersection of opposite Schubert cells in real full flag manifolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, flag-varieties

Let $F_n$ denote the full flag manifold consisting of all complete flags in $\mathbb{R}^n$. For the standard basis $\{ e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, denote the standard opposite flags:
$\sigma_- = \{e_1\} \subset \{e_1,e_2\} \subset\dots\subset \{ e_1,\dots,e_n\}$,
$\sigma_+ = \{e_n\} \subset \{e_n,e_{n-1}\} \subset\dots\subset \{ e_n,\dots,e_1\}$.

Notation: For a point $\sigma\in F_n$, denote by $C(\sigma)$ the set of all flags transverse to $\sigma$. This is known as a maximal Schubert cell.

Let $U_n$ denote the set of unipotent upper-triangular matrices in $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$. The maximal Schubert cell $C(\sigma_-)$ can be regarded as $U_n$ where the (fixed) identification $U_n \to C(\sigma_-)$ is given by $u\mapsto u\cdot \sigma_+$. The intersection $C(\sigma_+) \cap C(\sigma_-)$ is then seen as an open set in $U_n$ which is the complement of the union of the zero sets of $n-1$ polynomials $p_1,\dots,p_{n-1}$, where
$p_k (u) = \det u^{(k)}$ where $u^{(k)}$ denotes the upper-right $k\times k$ block matrix of $u$.

We define an involution $\iota: U_n\mapsto U_n$, $u\mapsto u^{-1}$. One can show that the involution preserves the intersection $C(\sigma_+) \cap C(\sigma_-)$.

An answer to the following question would be much appreciated.

**Question.** Does $\iota$ preserve any connected components of $C(\sigma_+) \cap C(\sigma_-)$?

When $n=3$ or $n \equiv 2\mod 4$, then it is not hard to show that $\iota$ does not preserve any connected components. I would like to know if this is true in general.

Comment: Are you familiar with the description of the connected components from https://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9704013 and https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9802093 ?

Comment: In terms of the parametrization in those papers, the map $u \mapsto u^{-1}$ should correspond to reflecting the triangular array over its antidiagonal and switching each binary entry to its complement. In the case of $n \equiv 2 \bmod 4$, I can see that this does not fix any orbit, because the middle "dual invariant" from the second paper will change. But how do you see that there are no solutions for $n \equiv 3 \bmod 4$?

Comment: Thank you, David. I don't know the answer to all $n\equiv 3\mod 4$ cases, I just know the answer when $n=3$ (in this case, there are six components, and the involution can be checked by picking representatives in each components). I have recently came to know about the two papers you mentioned. The way $u\mapsto u^{-1}$ acts on the orbits (as you mentioned), many connected components can be seen as not being preserved. E.g, when n is odd, which corresponds to n = even in the second paper (Theorem 2.2 (ii)) you cited, all the component corresponding to the non symmetric strata can be verified.

Comment: Moreover, in the above case, each symmetric strata consists of number of invariants (which are again not preserved) and two large orbits. I cannot see how the involution acts on these two orbits. I believe, with the aid of section 6.2 in the second paper, it is enough to check one symmetric strata.

When $n$ is even (corresponding to $n=$ odd case in the second paper), in a similar manner the orbits in the symmetric strata can be checked. However, the two large orbits in each non-symmetric strata seem nontrivial.

Comment: Yeah, I am in the same state. I am pretty sure that the $u \mapsto u^{-1}$ either switches the two large strata or sends them each to themself, but I don't know how to tell which.